# プロフィールページの行動履歴でタグ編集時の説明が英語のままになっている

Tags: バグ, 翻訳

プロフィールページの行動履歴で「投稿」一覧に "タグの要約" や "説明" を作成した際にログとして表示されますが、この部分が英語のままです。
なお、traducir や transifex で検索した限りでは翻訳できない状態です。

**表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: MSE にも報告済みです。 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361884